# How to save partial view viewmodel items in main view viewmodel with Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This might be a tricky question, but here it goes.

Let's say I have a main view and let's call it `MainView.cshtml`.

Now, `MainView.cshtml` has a dedicated ViewModel called `MainViewModel.cs` which holds a variable `Model.ExampleItems` which is an IEnumerable of class `ExampleItem`.

Now let's say I also have a partial view called `_PartialView.cshtml` whose ViewModel is just `ExampleItem`.

Okay so this is where I'm stuck. `MainView.cshtml` can dynamically call `_PartialView.cshtml` so that the user can create a new `ExampleItem`. How do I save each user-created `ExampleItem` to `MainViewModel`'s IEnumerable of ExampleItems?

Here is some example code

**MainView.cshtml**

```
@model Models.ViewModels.MainViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.ExampleItems)
{
   await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialView", item);
}

<button id="AddExampleItem" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Example Item</button>
```

**_PartialView.cshtml**

```
@model Models.ExampleItem

<input asp-for="VariableOne" />
<input asp-for="VariableTwo" />
<input asp-for="VariableThree" />
```

How can I save ^^^ this into the original `Model.ExampleItems`?

Comment: `IEnumerable of ExampleItems` is mainly for query.. to save, you probably want a `List` or a database table. Every time your user creates `ExampleItem` in your `_PartialView.cshtml`, store it in the DB. Then, every time you get your ExampleItems, you only need to query from the DB table.

Comment: Where do you want to do 'add item'? client side or server side?

Comment: @Dandy I forgot to include this part. This is all wrapped in a form... so basically after the user adds all of the new ExampleItems, they can hit submit and then it will be saved to our external db. However, when the ExampleItems are passed back to the controller on POST, it is an empty list

Comment: you can asynchronously post your partial view data by ajax, if this fits your problem of course. If you want, I can provide an example.

Comment: Can you show some more code? How user `adds all of the new ExcampleItems`? Are your posting new added `ExampleItems` using ajax or regular form post method?

Comment: Pass the partial view the collection if you have view constrains on form data... but you do not mention this... well you could get arround this by using the Id as the key. Ish you are correct is not easy to relay what im saying. But besides from this i would remove the model from the MainView.cshtml and make this part of extending pageBaseType to a custom BaseWebViewPage. this will simplify other aspects of viewmodel stuff

Comment: @SeM that would be great if you could. I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two paths forward here. Either way, in order to bind the posted `ExampleItem`s, the form fields must be named in the format `ExampleItems[N].Property`. So, to accomplish that, you can do:

1. Use a `for` loop, rather than a `foreach` and pass an `HtmlFieldPrefix`:

   ```
   @foreach (var i = 0; i < Model.ExampleItems; i++)
   {
      var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData);
      viewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "ExampleItems[" + i.ToString + "]";
      await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialView", Model.ExampleItems[i]);
   }
   ```

   You'll also need to make `ExampleItems` a `List<ExampleItem>` rather than `IEnumerable<ExampleItem>` or you'll raise an exception for enumerating twice (count and then for loop).
2. Create an editor template for `ExampleItem` and then utilize `EditorFor`. Just create a view at `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ExampleItem.cshtml`, and put your partial code there, instead. Then in your main view you would just do:

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExampleItems)
   ```

   Razor will intelligently determine that you passed it a collection and render the editor template for each item in the collection. Also, importantly, it will have the full context of the collection, so it will using proper name prefixes so that everything binds correctly on post.

Comment: This is awesome thanks for mentioning editor templates - I had completely forgotten about them. This worked great and looks a lot cleaner than the foreach loop I had. However, how would I go about adding a new ExampleItem to that original List of ExampleItems? On form submit, the new ExampleItem(s) get dropped completely

Comment: I'm assuming you're adding the fields for a new item dynamically via JavaScript, and if I had to guess, probably via an AJAX request that fetches the partial. In this case, the field names would not be properly prefixed, which is why the model binder discards them. I'd recommend using something like Knockout or Angular to generate your fields so that you can properly index the name attributes of the inputs based on their place in a JavaScript array.

Comment: Ugh yes I just looked you're right. I've never used either before, so I'll take a look at Knockout. Thanks for all of the help, man. I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer