# Data binding with asp-for inside nested loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I have a few blocks with lists of input on my site

```
<div id="MainClaimsBlock">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("UserClaimsBlock", Model.FirstClaimModel)
    @await Html.PartialAsync("UserClaimsBlock", Model.SecondClaimModel)
    @await Html.PartialAsync("UserClaimsBlock", Model.ThirdClaimModel)
    @await Html.PartialAsync("UserClaimsBlock", Model.FourthClaimModel)
</div>
```

And inside every partial view I have something like that (100+ lines in orig.)

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
    {
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Selected">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Selected">@Model.Categories[i].Name</label>
        </div>
    }
```

The problem is that I can't save values from these partial views because **asp-for** gives dublicated id and for properties for lists from partial views.

```
id="Model_SubCategories_6__Selected"
```

How do you distinguish the Id of one partial view from another?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, solution was found quite fast from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310232/how-to-save-partial-view-viewmodel-items-in-main-view-viewmodel-with-razor) by [Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt)

The solution is to use ViewDataDictionary before calling partial view

```
@{
    var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData);
    myViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Claims";
}

@await Html.PartialAsync("UserClaimsBlock", Model.SecondClaimModel, myViewData)
```

And after that asp-for tag returned id based on this prefix

```
id="Claims_Categories_2__Selected"
```